# Save RealityKit ModelEntity in Collada format

Tags: swift, scenekit, file-conversion, realitykit

I'm able to find converter `COLLADA` -> `GLTF` but not `USDZ` -> `COLLADA` and using Photogrammetry the only possible output is `.usdz`.

Is there a way to convert programmatically a RealityKit's ModelEntity in a `.dae` (Collada) format or better `glTF` format?

Thanks a lot, any input is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you cannot programmatically convert ModelEntity into `.dae` format. However, thanks to Maya 2022 and higher, you are now able to convert `.usdz` model to `.dae`, using [Maya USD plugin](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2022/ENU/Maya-USD/files/GUID-9E9D45F2-4DA9-497B-8D69-1573ED6B2BA8-html.html), or any Maya 2020 scene (and higher) into `.glTF` model using [Babylon.js](https://doc.babylonjs.com/extensions/Exporters/Maya_to_glTF).

Comment: Thanks, I have the same "opinion", I cannot find a way, RealityKit Entity can be load but not saved.